# Why is the word "former" dropped out when referring to a former vice president?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Context: In the recent (first) US Presidential Debate 2020, Chris Wallace (Moderator of the debate) referred Joe Biden as Vice President a number of times despite the fact he doesn't hold the office currently.

Is this the standard usage? (assuming ellipses) Isn't more apt to call him former VP?

Comment: The titles of President and Vice-President are, by convention and courtesy, held for life, even after the person no longer holds the office.

Comment: The same is true for many other positions, for example any Officer of the British armed forces retains their rank after they have retired, which is why you will sometimes see [retd.] appended for clarification.

Comment: @MikeBrockington - Only if they are Field Rank (Major/Squadron Leader/Lieutenant-Commander and above), according to Debretts, or have they changed that now? I know there's a slight exception for Captains (Army) if they are doing something equestrian, which is why you had Captain Mark Phillips, and I always wondered about Captain Peacock on _Are You Being Served?_ .

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Thanks - I'd forgotten that detail. In practice, it seems to be used for any Army Captain (or above) but that makes no significant difference to the general point.

Comment: Being a pedant, I pick it up. No self-respecting officer who retired as a Captain would bang on about his/her rank, I feel, and Debrett backs me up.

Comment: When I was in the school CCF, on Fridays our geography teacher became Flight Lieutenant Phillips; he had been an RAF meteorolgist during the war, but he never used his rank the rest of the time.